# Selenium using findElements

Tags: selenium, xpath

How can I automate to click the links enumerated by an item list.

```
*A
*B
*C
*D
*E

xpath of "*A" is html/body/ul/li[1]/a
xpath of "*B" is html/body/ul/li[2]/a
...
```

Is it possible to click all the items using `findElements(By.xpath)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use here findElement method  here you can use option to find element it will be more helpful for you. If you want example code than i can provide you  feel free to  ask me

Comment: hi, please help me from this problem.. :)

Comment: Here is exaample of html 

<select id="myID">
    <option value="ValueNo1">Option</option>
    <option value="ValueNo2">Not Option</option>
</select> 

 for this drop down code we want following code                                                 


WebElement mySelectElm = driver.findElement(By.id("mySelectID")); 
Select mySelect= new Select(mySelectElm);
selMySelect.selectByVisibleText("Option");

Answer (score 0):

First answer is yes but! in case that after click you will be not redirected to other page.

1. you need to create collection that will contain all the li.

```
IList<IWebElement> liCollection = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("html/body/ul")).FindElements(By.TagName("li");
```

2. you need to loop them one by one and invoke the click

   `for(int i = 0 ; i < liCollection.Count ; i++)
   {
       liCollection[i].FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Click;
       //Thread.Sleep(2000);
       liCollection = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("html/body/ul")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
   }`

**!!!STACKOVERFLOW CODE FORMAT PROBLEM!!!**

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you

```
    //count the list
    List<WebElement> ButtonNamelist=driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("html/body/ul"));
    int listcount=ButtonNamelist.size();

    for(int i=1;i<=listcount;i++){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/ul/li["+i+"]/a")).click();
    //you need to navigate back here to click on the other elements use waits to load the element and click again
    }
```